# Including "{" -sign in string.Format

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, formatting

I have a string which I want to insert an other string into. For this I use the method `string.Format()` but it doesn't work since my `basestring` include `{`-signs. As soon as I remove them from my string the code works fine.

```
 string baseString = "This is my base string and when it includes {-signs it {0}.";
 string insertString = "doesn't work";
 string completeString = string.Format(baseString, insertString);
```

Does someone have a glue about why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **'$'** for easy inserts into strings. For example:

```
string inputString = "test";
string anotherString = "test2";
int? codeExample = null;
string example = $"here I am putting my value: {inputString} and I can do it over and over {anotherString} or with code blocks {codeExample ?? 0}";

//result: here I am putting my value: test and I can do it over and over test2 or with code blocks 0
```

Reference: [Microsoft Language Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: I am pretty sure you misunderstood the OPs question. He want's to use a string like _some text with a funny curly bracket here { and a placeholder {0}_

Comment: That's no different than `String.Format`, it will fail in the same way if there are angle brackets in the format strings.

Comment: Its not exactly the same. You will get a compiler error if you put { in a $ string and if it is put in at runtime then it handles it gracefully and puts the curly brace into the string.